# Blender 3.0.0 Transparent PNG

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, transparency

Sorry if this is some common knowledge thing I've just not found, but searching has just had me find lots of ways how this used to be done in earlier versions of Blender.

I want to see the PNG alpha / transparency in the 3D view (Eevee) so that I can position it correctly, but despite messing around with lots of previous methods all I get is a black plane;
[image]

I couldn't get a mix shader to work and am getting frustrated with the various other options offered online.  The answer I found on here says to change the Blend Mode to one of the alpha options, but this does nothing as far as I can see.

[image]

This seems like something super simple but I can't figure it out - any help is appreciated!

EDIT: I've since upgraded to Blender 3.0.0 to keep on trying different things; will post here if I find the solution.

EDIT2:
So I cretae a new file and add the texture to the default cube.  Make the material a transparent alpha blend and turn off backface culling (which causes the texture to overdraw with the backface).
[image]

Changing to diffuse with alpha has a similar effect:
[image]

I have a reasonable understanding on how graphics rendering is done since I've been in the video game industry for quite a while, but can't find the part of the interface to enable this seemingly basic feature.

Render tab, vieport shading, material, texture, image settings, changing render modes...

I can just make the texture solid parts white (since it draws the ripped label in the corner of the cube without the black removing it) and then export a colour flipped version for the in-engine version.  Pretty odd workaround though, and I've seen lots of screenshots of people achieving this (and have done so myself in earlier Blender versions) so not sure what I'm missing now.

EDIT3: Solved :D

So I set up a mix shader again and got a similar result (possibly becuase I set it up wrong):
[image]

Then tried a Principled BSDF, which works:
[image]

It's very easy and streamlined, once you know where it is.  Seems odd that the mix shader didn't do it, since a lot of the stuff I found online indicates that being the primary method.  I just tripped over the Principled method in an image search so decided to give it a try.

Also seems like pretty simple functionality almost a 'Use Alpha Channel' checkbox sort of thing.  Anyway, it's working now - thanks a lot for the help guys.

[image]

Comment: Alpha blend is usually the best mode to try to start - not sure why it's not working for you, however, the first image shows evidence of z-fighting (2 faces sharing the same position) on the plane - perhaps the transparency is suffering because the plane is in the same place as the "wall".

Comment: No, the Z-Fighting isn't the culprit.  That just causes stripes as the motor tries to decide which surface is in front to draw first, not change the render content.

Will continue in the main question so I can post images.

Comment: Yeah, something's definitely wrong there. I get a greyed out cube - not a pure black one. What kind of GPU do you have?

Comment: Also, I can't see your node setup, but I assume you have the Alpha output from your image texture connected to the alpha input of the BSDF (or as a mix factor with a transparent shader), correct?

Comment: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2060 - but that's a good point, I didn't check if there was some compatability option or similar external to Blender mucking things up.

I did have the mix shader set up, then removed it becuase I couldn't get that to work either, will have another go.

The other reason I abandoned the mix shader was because a few years back I seem to remember doing this without needing it..

Comment: I would recommend using a _Mix Shader_ to combine your image texture (through whatever BSDF you're using for the material) with a _Transparent Shader_, using the Alpha output from your image texture as a _Mix Factor_. Assuming the Blend mode is set correctly, this should work. If it doesn't, then the problem is more likely related to graphics drivers or some kind of hardware/OpenGL issue.

Comment: In your images, the principled works - so use it if that's satisfactory. For the image with the shader mix, remove the alpha connection from the transparent bsdf, and connect it to the fac input of the mix shader instead.

Comment: Ok, thanks - that clarifies things.  

My use case is to export to Unity so just need the preview in Blender so I can precisely align UVs, with the Unity renderer and shader system taking over after export.

Just out of curiosity, what are the high level differences between Mix and Principled?  One is quicker to set up but less efficient?

Comment: At a glance, Mix is much more versatile as well.

Comment: Yeah. Principled is built for ease of setup - it's an "all in one shader" containing much of the other shader nodes. Like you said, mix gives more control, but that also comes with more work. Pick what's best for use-case. For you (just a preview), I would stick with the principled - it will work just fine.